# Single line statement in algorithm

Tags: algorithms

This is my latex code :

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}

\title{Euclid's Algorithm: An example of how to write algorithms in \LaTeX{}}

\author{write\LaTeX{}}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\section{Notations,Definitions and Symbols}

\begin{itemize}
{
\item $n$ is the number of vertice in a input graph $G$.

\item $S$ repersents implicit stack of size $n$.
\item $S'_{1}$ and $S'_{2}$ are the top two segments of stack $S$
\item $S'$ is explicit stack that contain $S'_1$ and $S'_2$, where size of both is $\Theta(\frac{n}{\ log n})$ many entries.
\item $D$ is a hash table.
\item $T$ is a trailer stack.
}
\end{itemize}



\section{Example Algorithm}

Algorithms can be included using the commands as shown in algorithm \ref{alg:euclid}.

\begin{algorithm}
\caption{DFS}\label{alg:dfs}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\For{\texttt{i:=1 to n}}
        \State \texttt{color[i]:= white }
      \EndFor
\STATE <Create a stack $S'$>


\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

I am getting, why `\STATE <Create a stack $S'$>` is not working.

Comment: When asking a question, please always specify _how_ something doesn't work. If you receive an error, then include the error message.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 1):

I assume this is about the `Undefined control sequence` error this throws. It does that because, well, `\STATE` isn't a defined control sequence here. But the command `\State`, which you also use, is, so use that.